# Postman Validate key-value pair corresponding to another key-value pair

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-testcase

The Response body is like:

```
[
    [
        {   
          "id": "1",
          "status": false
        },
        {           
            "id": "1",
            "status": false
        }
    ],
    [
        {           
            "id": "2",
            "status": true
        }
    ]
]
```

I have to validate if id =1, status should be false, Test gets passed

I tried this:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();

for(var i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++)
 {
   if (jsonData[i][i].Id==="1")
    {

    if (jsonData[i][i].status=== false)
      {

        pm.test("Holiday Update is Sucssesful");
        }
```

​          }
}
But this one is getting invalid token error

Comment: Please share the test code that you written and attempted to run so far and any error messages that you're seeing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postman test script has support for chai assertions.

```js
var jsonData = pm.response.json();

for (subArray of jsonData){
    for (subSubArray of subArray){
        if (subSubArray.id == 1){
            pm.test("id with 1 has status false", ()=>{
                pm.expect(subSubArray.status).to.eql(false)
            })
        }
    }

}
```